# Windows 11 iTunes taksbar icon displaying with white square

Tags: windows

just upgraded to Windows 11, but the iTunes taskbar icon looks... bad. Instead of a full icon image it's tiny with an ugly white square surrounding it. Any way to fix?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O48YL.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Just upgraded to Windows 11, but the iTunes taskbar icon looks... bad.
> Instead of a full icon image it's tiny with an ugly white square
> surrounding it. Any way to fix?

Not here.  Windows 11 Pro. The task bar iTunes icon is identical to the Desktop Icon only a bit smaller (same as Windows 10).

Two things:

(A) Uninstall iTunes completely (Control Panel, Programs and Features) (iTunes
Quick Time
Apple Software Update
Apple Mobile Device Support
Bonjour
Apple Application Support).

Restart and install the latest version of iTunes and check the task bar icon. It is best to download iTunes from the iTunes website (Apple) and not from the Microsoft Store.

(B) If not fixed in (A) and since you just upgraded to Windows 11, the upgrade may not have been completely correct. Try a Windows 11 Repair Install and use the option to Keep Everything.

Windows 11 Repair is here:  Second Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11